# HealthKit - Cannot authorize HKActivitySummaryType

Tags: ios, authorization, healthkit, ios10

I've been searching the internet for a couple of days now because I can't seem to authorize my app to read the HKActivitySummaryType.
Every other type works, just this one type for some reason is not included in Apple's HealthKit authorization screen.

This is my code for reading data:

```
private func dataToRead() -> Set<HKObjectType> {  
    let activeEnergyBurnedType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)  
    let weightType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)  
    let heightType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)  
    let dateOfBirth = HKCharacteristicType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .dateOfBirth)  
    let activitySummary = HKObjectType.activitySummaryType()  
    let workoutType = HKObjectType.workoutType()  

    return Set(arrayLiteral: activeEnergyBurnedType!, weightType!, heightType!, dateOfBirth!, activitySummary, workoutType)  
}
```

I really hope somebody here can help me, because I'm clueless.

Comment: IOS Version? This is available singe 9.3

Comment: Look at Health App -> your App. Can you see it there?

Comment: Hi Gerd, I am using iOS 10 Beta 4. Yes, I can see my app in Health App. As I said, every other type I request authorization for shows up, just not the activitySummaryType.

Comment: In Health App -> Your App: do you see ActivitySummary?

Comment: My guess is that you have already approved it or something like that

Comment: No, I don't see activity summary listed there. When running my app from Xcode I get a message in the debugger that I have not authorized activity summary. I'm displaying a HKActivityRingView in my app, when trying to set its value, I get the message.